# ‘libjemalloc.so’: No such file or directory

Tags: julia, mxnet

I installed Julia and was trying to install MXNet for Julia. While setting the MXNet-Julia environment, I found that there is no file called libjemalloc.so.
I was following this link: https://mxnet.apache.org/get_started/ubuntu_setup#build-the-shared-library

Can someone tell me what is the problem.